# optimize integers using GA package

Tags: r, genetic-algorithms

The GA package is a great package to use Genetic Algorithm for optimization. See for example [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GA/vignettes/GA.html). I have a use case, where my possible values are integer (e.g. 1, 2, 4 ...). So far, I simply rounded the real values in my fitness function. Is there a better way to encode integers? Thanks!